# How to copy ntfs permissions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, security

I found a method for copying ntfs permissions information from one existing folder to a newly created one - I'm not sure if it's doing the work it should do. Maybe one can have a look at the method and give some comments:

```
private static void CopySecurityInformation(String source, String dest)
{
    FileSecurity fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(
        source,
        AccessControlSections.All);
    FileAttributes fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(source);
    File.SetAccessControl(dest, fileSecurity);
    File.SetAttributes(dest, fileAttributes);
}
```

Thanks for your help,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does slightly more than just copying the NTFS permissions. It also copies the attributes of the file. I'm not quite certain whether it copies inherited permissions, though, but run it once and you should be able to find out.

Note that copying permissions on and of itself requires special permissions (administrators have these, of course), be sure the process running this method has the required permissions to query, view and set permissions on those objects.

Comment: Well - copying permissions _and_ attributes was exactly the behaviour I wanted to achieve. - sorry I didn't tell you before... ;-)

And yes, the application ensures that the administrator account is used.

Answer (score 3):

I tried following the OP suggested pattern for copying a file's ACLs and attributes and found a few issues in our application. Hopefully this information helps others.

According to MSDN, using the [`File.SetAccessControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) method as shown above will not work.

> The SetAccessControl method persists only FileSecurity objects that
>   have been modified after object creation.  If a FileSecurity object
>   has not been modified, it will not be persisted to a file.  Therefore,
>   *it is not possible to retrieve a FileSecurity object from one file and
>   reapply the same object to another file*.

It is necessary to make a new `FileSecurity` object for the destination file and assign to this a copy of the source `FileSecurity` object.

Here is an example of a pattern that works from our app.

```
    public static void CopyFile(string source, string destination)
    {
        // Copy the file
        File.Copy(source, destination, true);

        // Get the source file's ACLs
        FileSecurity fileSecuritySource = File.GetAccessControl(source, AccessControlSections.All);
        string sddlSource = fileSecuritySource.GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(AccessControlSections.All);

        // Create the destination file's ACLs
        FileSecurity fileSecurityDestination = new FileSecurity();
        fileSecurityDestination.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(sddlSource);

        // Set the destination file's ACLs
        File.SetAccessControl(destination, fileSecurityDestination);

        // copy the file attributes now
        FileAttributes fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(source);
        File.SetAttributes(destination, fileAttributes);
    }
```

After fixing the first issue, then we found the owner attribute was not being copied. Instead, the destination file was owned by Administrator in our case. To get around that the process needs to enable the SE_RESTORE_NAME privilege. Check out [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/AdjustTokenPrivileges.html) on pinvoke.net for a complete Privileges class that makes setting privileges easy.

The last thing that we had to deal with was UAC. We needed to restart our app with administrative rights if the user is running under UAC. Here is another example from our app that deals with relaunching the app with elevated privileges.

```
    private static void RelaunchWithAdministratorRights(string[] args)
    {
        // Launch as administrator
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string executablePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        processStartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        if (args != null && args.Count() > 0)
        {
            string arguments = args[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < args.Count(); i++)
                arguments += " " + args[i];
            processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        }

        try
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // The user refused to allow privileges elevation. Do nothing and return directly ...
        }

        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Ours was a console app so we need to pass the `args` parameter from the `Main` method to the `RelaunchWithAdministratorRights(args)`. Non-console apps could pass null instead. We call `RelaunchWithAdministratorRights` from within `catch` blocks as in:

```
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            RelaunchWithAdministratorRights(args);
            return;
        }
```

In our app we just return after the call to `RelaunchWithAdministratorRights` to exit the instance of the app that lacked privileges. Depending on your app, you may prefer to `throw` your way out. Regardless, after returning from `RelaunchWithAdministratorRights` you don't want this instance to continue processing.

Enjoy!

Comment: Very old question - but many thanks Gyle for sharing your own results.